# How can error GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown be fixed?

Tags: linux, gnome

I'm trying to customize Ubuntu 22.04. But then i'm entering

```
sudo gnome-tweaks
```

it returns

```
WARNING : Error getting shell mode
CRITICAL: Error getting shell version
WARNING : Could not list shell extensions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_appearance.py", line 144, in __init__
    extensions = self._shell.list_extensions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 76, in list_extensions
    return self._proxy.proxy_extensions.ListExtensions()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", line 349, in __call__
    result = self.dbus_proxy.call_sync(self.method_name, arg_variant,
gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files (2)
```

Gnome-tweaks opens, but... If i change some parameters in gnome-tweaks, it does just nothing! What can I do with it?

Comment: You shouldn't be running gnome-tweaks with `sudo`. Also, this is not a programming or software engineering related question, so it's not really suited for StackOverflow

Comment: But if i run them without sudo, i don't get this erorr neither nothing changes are applied to system.